# Regular Expression to match string after specific word until dot

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
Dažikliai. Nepavojingas. Savybės: Geltonas ekstrahuojamas iš kurkumos, neapalo šaknies. Arba gaunamas sintezės būdu.
```

and I want to match a word after static string `Savybės`. until first dot.

So my output should be:

```
Geltonas ekstrahuojamas iš kurkumos, neapalo šaknies
```

Here what I try so far

```
"/^Savybės=*$/"
```

but this doesn't give any results.

Comment: Your current regex is trying to match from the beginning of the string `^`.  Yet your string does not start with: `Savybės`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a positive lookbehind:

[**Regex101 example**](https://regex101.com/r/qI6qF4/1)

```
(?<=Savybės:\s).*?(?=\.)
```

Input:

> Dažikliai. Nepavojingas. Savybės: Geltonas ekstrahuojamas iš kurkumos, neapalo šaknies. Arba gaunamas sintezės būdu.

Matches:

> Geltonas ekstrahuojamas iš kurkumos, neapalo šaknies

---

If you want to include the `.` character at the end:

[**Regex101 example**](https://regex101.com/r/wK7zY7/1)

```
(?<=Savybės:\s).*?\.
```

Input:

> Dažikliai. Nepavojingas. Savybės: Geltonas ekstrahuojamas iš kurkumos, neapalo šaknies. Arba gaunamas sintezės būdu.

Matches:

> Geltonas ekstrahuojamas iš kurkumos, neapalo šaknies.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a lookbehind and lazy dot matching that are inefficient. You can just use a capturing group and a negated character class to match any character but a dot:

```
$re = '/\bSavybės:\s*([^.]*)/u'; 
$str = "Dažikliai. Nepavojingas. Savybės: Geltonas ekstrahuojamas iš kurkumos, neapalo šaknies. Arba gaunamas sintezės būdu."; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/0Eg7wy) (note the `/u` modifier, too)

The regex matches:

- `\b` - word boundary (so as not to match any word that contains "Savybės")
- `Savybės:` - literal `Savybės:` character sequence
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `([^.]*)` - capture group #1 that will hold our value matching 0 or more characters other than a literal `.`

**It takes [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/tR2dI1/2) 14 steps to return the valid match, and it takes [`(?<=Savybės:\s).*?(?=\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/tR2dI1/2) 179 steps.**